# Running cURL from Python in Windows

Tags: python, windows, curl

I'm trying to use os.system() to run curl and I'm getting an error:

```
os.system("C:\\Windows\\System32\\curl.exe")
```

'C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,    operable program or batch file.

I've also tried just `os.system("curl")` since it's in the path, but I get the same error. If I switch "curl" to "python", it works fine. Is there any way to get this to work?

Thanks

Comment: you have curl installed haven't you? If so, where did you install it? If it came with an installer it's most probably located in "program files"

Comment: You have this error because C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe does not exist. Try to invoke it from a command prompt and you will see the error.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should've mentioned. It exists as that's where I put the exe. I put it there so that it would be in the path (couldn't be bothered to add it specifically to the path).Running it from the command prompt works fine.

Comment: Are you running as a "run as administrator"?
This exception can present itself if you do not have permission to execute files which are under sys32.
Also, try to move 'curl.exe' to 'C:\', and run it from there...

Comment: Try copy curl.exe to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` in case you are using a 64 bit Windows and a 32 bit Python.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you add the bin directory of your curl installation to the PATH of your system. for instance: ';c:\curl\bin' Remember to add the ";" to separate the entries in the PATH.